# Issue executing transaction from Gnosis Safe (compensation to you if you resolve)

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe, gnosis

We have been trying to capture funds from a smart contract, that holds the funds.  We are getting errors attempting to execute from the Gnosis interface.  The transaction has three addresses that have confirmed/signed but when trying to execute, meta mask gives an error.  We have tried changing the gas amounts to no avail. If you can help us to execute this transaction and we receive the funds, we will pay $500 for your efforts. Please see screenshots and also transaction link. Error code shown is GS020 on BSC Scan and error 400 is shown on metamask.

[BSC Transaction Error Example - not the actual transaction being discussed](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x282779829d04e2c827f191583421a73537990220f6da4685d0312281a26e3e36)

[Link to Contract code](https://bscscan.com/address/0xdf0bdb1aaef707ac84297229dcceb21cfcf09a81#code)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your [first](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x282779829d04e2c827f191583421a73537990220f6da4685d0312281a26e3e36) example tx - is just the `OnChain Rejection`.  The [#57](https://gnosis-safe.io/app/bnb:0xdF0bDB1AaEf707AC84297229DCCeB21cfcF09A81/transactions/queue) is still pending. The tx calls `withdrawFunds()` of the contract [0x1D8769b57aaf4E3C0A64fC2f035F1EfA134FE24c](https://bscscan.com/bytecode-decompiler?a=0x1D8769b57aaf4E3C0A64fC2f035F1EfA134FE24c). The tx looks good - all `requires` should be passed - the `state` is `3` and `assetManagerAddress` is your multisig.

So despit of the error message in tx simulation, you can click `Submit` button anyway.

###### EDIT

Looked into the decompiled code:

```csharp
def withdrawFund(): # not payable
  require state <= 5
  if state != 3:
      revert with 0, 'ONLY_DURING_SUCCESS'
  if assetManagerAddress != caller:
      revert with 0, 'ONLY_ASSET_MANAGER'
  call assetManagerAddress with:
     value eth.balance(this.address) wei
       gas 2300 * is_zero(value) wei
  if not ext_call.success:
      revert with ext_call.return_data[0 len return_data.size]
```

but as the gnosis safe emits the `Event` when the native token(BNB) is received

```csharp
contract EtherPaymentFallback {
    event SafeReceived(address indexed sender, uint256 value);

    /// @dev Fallback function accepts Ether transactions.
    receive() external payable {
        emit SafeReceived(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }
}
```

You will get here the `Out of Gas` error, as `2300` won't be enough to transfer BNB and emit the `Event`. The most easy solution would be to change the `assetManagerAddress` to EOA and call the `withdrawFund` from it, or if you must stay with Multisig as the `Manager`, you could deploy a new Gnosis Safe implementation, to prevent emitting that `Event`, or to look into `accessList` - https://github.com/folia-app/eip-2929

Comment: Thanks for your response. It seems like you might have a good solution. If you are confident this should work, would you be willing to walk us through the process on a video call or something? Again, will pay $500 if it does work. We are a reputable start up. I saw you have a blog site, should I contact you through there?

Comment: Sure, or you can email me (_I've updated my profile page_)

Comment: you can check out this repo https://github.com/rmeissner/safe-migrator

Comment: @tenbits Where do I find your email? I can't seem to locate it

Comment: @doc8591 https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/68115/tenbits?tab=profile  It is in the About section of the Profile page. _Stackoverflow doesn't have extra public email section_